# Is it able to create folders with Python?

Tags: python

I am writing a Pokemon game and I want to make folders to save different types of Pokemon, as well as other sorts of information, in. I want to use folders because it would be really messy if I were to save all my data into a single file.

Is it possible to create folders with a Python program?  This would make it easier and cleaner for me when I try to import the Pokemon data from external websites.

Comment: "not txt, those which you organise your stuff with" - _what??_ You mean, 'folders', right?

Comment: Yes Sorry my English is bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run any command that you want with python by doing:

```
import os
os.popen("mkdir random_name") # This creates a directory called "random_name"
os.popen("touch rando_name.txt") # This creates a file called "random_name"
```

You can run any command that you would usually run in terminal inside the popen.

You can use the popen() command in both UNIX(Linux, macOS) as well as Windows OS.
You can learn more regarding this by taking a look in the python documentation.
https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

Comment: Is this problematic in a security sense?  (I don't know, I'm genuinely asking.)  I could imagine that it might be suboptimal for a service with an open web connection to have OS access ...

Comment: Not really sure. If you want to use in production as a web application probably not the wisest thing to do.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) with the `a` mode, which opens a file in append mode, and creates it if it does not exist:

```
my_file = open('file.txt', 'a')
# Optionally: write stuff to my_file, using my_file.write('stuff')
my_file.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to create folders (or *directories*), you need [`os.mkdir`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html):

```
import os 

os.mkdir("folder_name")
```

To create some *deep* folders at once, use `os.makedirs`:

```
os.makedirs("path/to/something")
```

Then all that structure of three folders will be created.

Tutorialspoint has a short [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_mkdir.htm) about `os.mkdir`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`with statement`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) like this:

```
with open('some_file_100.txt', 'a') as f:
    pass
```

The above will just create an empty file, if you want to write something to the created file, you can try:

```
with open('some_file_100.txt', 'a') as f:
    f.write('some text')
```

When you use [`with statement`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) you do not need to close your files explicitly because they are closed autmatically at the end of the block.